# What happens if you apply a template with a level adjustment when already at level 20?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-templates

Level 20 is the max level before epic levels in D&D 3.5e and some games don't even use epic levels, so if you apply a template with a level adjustment (e.g ghost with a LA of +4) at level 20 what happens? Does the LA just do nothing as no more leveling up will occur or is it impossible to apply the template?

Comment: Hi Dan, and welcome to RPG Stack Exchange. Check out our [tour] to see how we work, and when you reach 20 reputation, you can join us in [chat].

Answer (score 8):

Nothing. Your ECL is 20 + the LA, which is used to calculate the XP necessary for the next level, but there *is no* XP necessary for the next level because there is no next level, so your ECL no longer has any relevance.